# Convert strtotime to date format in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime

I need to convert `strtotime` to date time format in sql query

```
Ex: 

Strtotime - 05132512345
Date Format - 05/31/19
```

Comment: Please tag your DB Engine. Also please see [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you need to show us what you have tried.

Comment: Also please explain what a *"strtotime"* value is.  Is it in the database?

Answer (score 0):

If strtotime is the Unix time (number of seconds since 1/1/1970), you could do the following formula:  (Microsoft SQL Server)

```
select dateadd(minute,cast(5132512345/60 as int),'1/1/1970')
```

However, your numeric value does not return 5/31/2019.

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. Please mention for which DBMS product this works.